# Change MaterialBarcodeScanner scanner result

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Below is one of the existing `MaterialBarcodeScanner` library.

`MaterialBarcodeScanner`: Easy to use barcode reader for your Android Project (Uses Google Mobile Vision API).

1) Provide gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'
```

2) Build a `MaterialBarcodeScanner`

```
private void startScan() {
    /**
     * Build a new MaterialBarcodeScanner
     */
    final MaterialBarcodeScanner mBarcodeScanner 
             = new MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder()
            .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
            .withEnableAutoFocus(true)
            .withBleepEnabled(true)
            .withBackfacingCamera()
            .withText("Scanning...")
            .withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
                    barcodeResult = barcode;
                    result.setText(barcode.rawValue);
                }
            })
            .build();
    mBarcodeScanner.startScan();
}
```

3) Hook it up to a button

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 startScan();
}
});
```

- I already integrated this code as a module library but how can I change the result of this method programmatically -> public void onResult(Barcode barcode)?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to change in this method? Can you be little more specific about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just want to send a notification when the scanning is successful. I already have the notification code implement on my MainActivity but I don't know how to add it in this part of the code:
 `.withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
                    barcodeResult = barcode;
                    result.setText(barcode.rawValue);
                }
            })`